# How do I loop through a 2D array in lua

Tags: arrays, for-loop, lua, add-on, world-of-warcraft

I am attempting to make a WoW addon and am saving some guild data in a 2D array. I have successfully saved the data to the array but am having trouble getting it back out.

```
local playerName = UnitName("player");
ChatFrame1:AddMessage('Hi my name is: ' .. playerName);

local guildMembers = {}

local totalMembers, onlineMembers = GetNumGuildMembers();
local visibleMembers = onlineMembers;
local guildMembers = {}

if ( GetGuildRosterShowOffline() ) then
   visibleMembers = totalMembers;
end

for index=1, visibleMembers do
   local name = GetGuildRosterInfo(index);
   local weeklyXP = GetGuildRosterContribution(index);
   guildMembers[index] = {}
   guildMembers[index][1] = name;
   guildMembers[index][2] = weeklyXP;
   --DEFAULT_CHAT_FRAME:AddMessage('name: '..guildMembers[index][1]..' weeklyXP: '..guildMembers[index][2]);
end

for i, v in pairs(guildMembers) do
   for j, v2 in pairs(i) do
      print(i.. ': ' ..v.. ' xp: ' ..v2);
   end
end
```

Everything seems to work but for the last nested for loop. Just a note, my array may skip numbers. I have Google it but most of the questions asked knew how long their array was and I do not. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The take away from the 2 answers below is that you should not treat your list of `guildMembers` as a 2D array since that's a bit obtuse to work with. Instead, work with it from the point of view of a 1D list of `guildMembers`. Each member(item on list) is a table or object that stores the information you need.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a numerical for loop instead of a generic one.

```lua
-- The # operator gets the length of a table
for i = 1, #guildMembers, 1 do
    print(i.." - Name: "..guildMembers[i][1].."; XP: "..guildMembers[i][2]);
end
```

Or you could use a dictionary:

```lua
local guildMembers = {
    name1 = weeklyXP1;
    name2 = weeklyXP2;
};
for name, xp in pairs(guildMembers) do
    print(name..": "..xp);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `pairs(v)` in inner loop, not `pairs(i)`, and I think you want `..j..` not `..v..`:

```
   for j, v2 in pairs(v) do
      print(i.. ': ' ..j.. ' xp: ' ..v2);
   end
```

But you should use a map for the inner part, as in

```
guildMembers[index] = {name=name, xp=weeklyXP}
```

then inner loop becomes

```
   for j, v2 in pairs(v) do
      print(i.. ': ' ..j.. ' = ' ..v2);
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

To loop through a 2D array, you can an inner and outer `ipairs()` iterator, or an 'index' in a regular `for do` loop for numerical indexes in order. You can also use `pairs()` with all index types like numbers and strings, but will be in an 'undefined' order.

You use both fine except that farther down in your code, you have a `pairs` vs. `ipairs` issue basically assuming you wanted it 'in order', along with other signs of frustration in the code :). This confusion is very common. You also tried to iterate over the inner array incorrectly, you can just access them directly be index. You can do `for j,v2 in ipairs(v) do` which is pretty much an idiom for this kind of thing.

In Lua tables 'contain' both array like indexed data, **and** name/value pair data, and they are separate internally and have 'sometimes' different semantics. In the case of 'pairs' iterators, they are different. :) The `ipairs()` operates on the 'indexed' data, and `pairs()` iterates the name / value data. When you added rows using `bob[i]=fred;` you were adding to the 'indexed' part of the table, due to the various rules that govern this.

**If wanted just the inner elements, treat the outer (and inner) like any table:**

```
for i, v in ipairs(guildMembers) do print(v[1] .. ':' ..v[2]) end
```

**Otherwise get an inner element, and just rinse and repeat:**

```
for i,v in ipairs(x) do for j,v2 in ipairs(v) do print(v2) end end
```

**Here is a mockup that can be tested by itself:**

```
local guildMembers = {}
local visibleMembers = 10;

if visibleMembers then

    -- building using 'for'
    for index = 1, visibleMembers do
        local name = "name" .. index --GetGuildRosterInfo(index);
        local weeklyXP = index * 12345 --GetGuildRosterContribution(index);
        guildMembers[index] = {}
        guildMembers[index][1] = name;
        guildMembers[index][2] = weeklyXP;
    end

    -- reading using 'ipairs'
    for i, v in ipairs(guildMembers) do
        print(i.. ': ' ..v[1].. ' xp: ' ..v[2]);
    end
    -- or
    for i, v in ipairs(guildMembers) do
        for j, v2 in ipairs(v)    -- takes the 'object' in 'v' and iterates sub
            print(i..' '..j.. ': ' ..v2.. 'name or xp');
        end
    end

end
```

**Here is your code redone, which will probably work as is:**

```
-- say my name
local playerName = UnitName("player");
ChatFrame1:AddMessage('Hi my name is: ' .. playerName);

-- locals
local guildMembers = {}

local totalMembers, onlineMembers = GetNumGuildMembers();
local visibleMembers = onlineMembers;

if thenGetGuildRosterShowOffline() then
    visibleMembers = totalMembers;
end

if visibleMembers then  
    -- build list
    for index=1, visibleMembers do
        local name = GetGuildRosterInfo(index);
        local weeklyXP = GetGuildRosterContribution(index);

        -- method 1   (ordered in likeliness of least to most expensive)
        --guildMembers[index] = { name, weeklyXP, }

        -- method 2
        --tinsert(guildMembers, { name, weeklyXP, })

        -- method 3
        --local item = { }; item[1] = name; item[2] = weeklyXP;
        --guildMembers[index] = item

        -- method 4 - original
        guildMembers[index] = {}
        guildMembers[index][1] = name;
        guildMembers[index][2] = weeklyXP;

        --DEFAULT_CHAT_FRAME:AddMessage('name: '..guildMembers[index][1]..
        --    ' weeklyXP: '..guildMembers[index][2]);
    end
    -- print
    for i, v in ipairs(guildMembers) do
        --for j, v2 in ipairs(i) do -- dont want loop if print in same line                     print(i.. ': ' ..v[1].. ' xp: ' ..v[2]);
        --end
    end
end
```